# change icon background color lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, icon-name

The aqua color icon is visible on the UI, and I want a blue background. The flight white color is fine; only the background color has to change. using icon-name="custom:custom20"

[image]

```
 <c-Flight-Search obj-name="flight__c" search-placeholder="From" icon-name="custom:custom20" onclick={handleSet}>
 </c-Flight-Search>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi as per this documentation [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/#Styling-Hooks-Overview), you can change the background colour using the css styling hooks

You can add this lines to your
.css file

```
:host{
    --slds-c-icon-color-background: blue; 
}
```

Change the blue to preferred color, using whichever method you prefer :)

After adding the above css, this is how my icon looks like:
[image]

Hope it helps!

Edit:

.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom20" class="changethis">
        </lightning-icon>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom20">
        </lightning-icon>
   </lightning-card>
```

.css

```
.changethis{
--slds-c-icon-color-background: blue;
}
```

this will make sure only the icon with the class="changethis" will have the background color changed.

Comment: :host impacted all other icons like dropdown icon also changed!!!. I want only airplane background color only @prem22

Comment: then just add a class to the tags that you to change the colour and apply the css to those class only, I have edited my answer added some code examples for you above